# How to change only elements of one array that are missing in another in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, element

If I have 2 arrays, for example a = [**1**, 2, 3, **4**, 5] and b = [**4**, 7, 9, **1**]

and I want to use a method to change elements of the first one. For example

```
a.map {|x| x.to_s}
```

but I don't want to change elements that are the same as in the array b.
In this case my desire result would be

```
a = [1, "2", "3", 4, "5"]
```

1 and 4 are still integers, because the array b has this elements.

So how can I implement this task?

arrays and methods are used just for example to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this with a simple ternary operator inside your map block to either add the respective element as is or as a string depending on whether the second array contains an element with that value:

```
a.map { |x| (b.include? x) ? x : x.to_s }
```

Comment: downvoter please explain reason for downvote... this was tested in irb and yields exactly what OP said was his desired result

Comment: The reason is probably that you haven't explained your answer. You should explain how op was wrong, and how this code line is better, even if it seems obvious to your trained eye.

Comment: Fair point; have updated my answer. A bit harsh for someone to downvote a correct answer for that though when a comment like yours is much more constructive.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.map!{|e| b.include?(e) ? e : e.to_s}
```

Comment: ...and if the arrays are large, first convert `b` to a set.